# S3 Data Loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket that gets data loaded into it daily. I am still pretty new to this process, but was wondering what the most cost-effective and efficient way to be able to query the data would be? I am considering a Lambda function to aggregate the data within the S3 buckets, and then either loading it into a Redshift schema, or query it directly with Athena.

Are there better alternatives? Different data warehouses I should consider? Cost is a priority, but ultimately this needs to be a scalable solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Querying it directly, as-is, with Athena is going to be the easiest way, as long as the data is in a format Athena can work with. It's difficult to comment on cost of different solutions without knowing the size of your data set.

Comment: @MarkB Totally makes sense. The data is uploaded into the s3 bucket as daily files, ranging from 70-200MB files. They are distinct days being uploaded, so I definitely would need to append them at some point.